# Org-mode custom heading numbering?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'd like to export an org buffer to HTML and have the heading numbering not always start at 1, rather, a given number. I plan to have a sequence of org buffers be "chapters." So the first org buffer, Chapter 1, can export with headings starting at 1, but the next, Chapter 2, should start at 2 ... so on and so forth. Can this be done?

Comment: It is better IMO, to use `#+INCLUDE` for that purpose: have a master file with the chapter headings and the `#INCLUDE`s and have the included chapters start from the section down. If you export the "chapters", interpret the numbers as section numbers, but when you export the master file, everything works as expected. This is a similar trick to what Lamport recommends in the LaTeX book, p. 72 ("Splitting your input").

Comment: Yes, this works, but now the separate pages are all rolled into one big HTML page. Not a big deal, but is there any way to keep them separate and keep the numbering behavior?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not sure. You might want to investigate `texinfo` export (and thence to HTML), instead of using the HTML exporter directly. The Org mode manual does this, so it can serve as an example.